# Two names for Moshiach in Lecha Dodi

Tags: shabbat, messiah, song-poetry, kabbalat-shabbat

Lecha Dodi refers to moshiach twice. The first time, he is called "the son of Yishai." Later on, he is referred to as "the man descended from Peretz." We know that the piyut's author, Rav Alkabetz, was an important mekubal and that the Arizal was very impressed with this piyut. Given the kabbalistic provenance of the song, one can assume that there is a deeper meaning behind the specific phrasing used. What is the significance of the two different appellations?

Comment: Because "Ben Dovid" doesn't rhyme in the song with the rest of the words?

Comment: My analysis - The 1st "half" of Lecha Dodi (Up to & including "Hit'orir") focus on Shabbat and Jerusalem. The verse that has *ben Yishai* talks about Jerusalem awaking for the dust, and mentions "ben Yishai* who is clearly David who was responsible for uniting and conquering Jerusalem. The 2nd half of Lecha Dodi talks about the future & mentions Mashiach, in a sense. "Ish ben Partzi" means " a man the son (or descendant) of Peretz." Clearly, David is not the direct son of Peretz, so I think this is a general description of Mashiach, not specifically David.

Comment: @DanF Interesting. Are you saying that the two appellations actually don't refer to the same person?

Comment: How do 'we' know these facts about lekha dodi?

Comment: @mevaqesh See www.beureihatefilah.org for a digest that explains the format of Lecha Dodi. He cites other sources. As for my analysis, what do you lnow? It seems that from the answer, below, I was along the right track.

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi [Eliyahu Akiva Rabinowitz](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A5') at a Knessiah in Krakow as recorded in [HaPeles - year 1904](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=12940&st=&pgnum=448) explains as follows.

The first phrase which mentions Ben Yishai is discussing the beginning of the redemption where people will have to do Teshuva for all their sins. The second phrase which mentions Ben Partzi is at a later stage where according to Sanhedrin 98b it can be a different personality, so long it is from Shevet Yehuda, therefore it says Ben Partzi.

> לזה אומרים על יד בן ישי בית  הלחמי — שהקים עולה של תשובה — קרבה אל
>   נפשי [דייקא] גאלה, הגאל הנפש  ותחלץ מן המצר. משא"כ בחרוז השני המדבר
>   בגאולתן של ישראל מן הגלות ושיבתם  אל אדמתם, שכבר אינו מוכרח להיות דוקא
>   ע"י דוד בן ישי וכמאמז"ל בסנהדרין צ״ח: .עתיד הקב"ה לחעמיד להם דוד אחר
>   שנאמר: ועבדו אח ה׳ וכו׳ ואת דוד מלכם אשר  אקים להם, הקים לא נאמר אלא
>   אקים עיי״ש ובכן הלא יוכל היות דוד אחר רק שיהא  משבט יהודה ומבית פרץ
>   כידוע שמלך פורץ גדר כו' ולכן כשאנו אומרים ימין ושמאל  תפרוצי ואת ה׳
>   תעריצי״, שוב איננו צריכין לאמר דוקא ע"י בן ישי בית הלחמי, רק  אומרים
>   אנו סתם על יד איש בן פרצי נשמחה ונגילה

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Shlomo Alkabetz, the author of Lecha Dodi, was the teacher of Rabbi Moshe Kordovero who led the Kabbalists in Tzfat before the Ari z"l arrived.

There are many dimensions to his poem/song. One of them is that the regular weekdays are compared to the time of exile (עולם הזה) and Shabbat to the time of the coming of Moshiach and the final redemption (ימות המשיח ועולם הבא).

This is alluded to in the repeating verse, Lecha *Dodi* (לכה דודי), *Come out My beloved*. That *Dodi* (**דודי**) is referring to the final stage of Moshiach ben David (משיח בן **דויד**), also called *Melech HaMoshiach*, which is the culmination of the final redemption (גאולה שלימה). This is in contrast to Moshiach ben David without the addition of the letter 'Yud' (משיח בן דוד) which refers to an earlier stage in the redemption.

This is discussed by [the Vilna Gaon in Kol HaTor, 2:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%91_%D7%91) and the concept of the union of Moshiach ben Yosef and Moshiach ben David (משיח בן יוסף משיח בן דויד גמטריא אלף).

> **לפעמים** **מתחלקים תפקידיהם של ב׳ המשיחין** הן בדרגות והן בהשפעות תלוי לפי הבחינה אם בבחינת לאה ורחל, היינו דעת ומלכות הרי מב״ד הוא המשפיע את השפע העליון ומב״י הוא המקבל ומוציא לפועל בבחינת יהודה שהציל את יוסף, ואם בבחינת יוסף ויהודה היינו יסוד ומלכות, הרי מב״י הוא המשפיע ומב״ד הוא המקבל. **וכל זאת באתחלתא דגאולה בזמן שעץ יוסף ועץ יהודה הם ״אחדים בידך״, כשהם עדיין כתרי פלגא גופא** בדרגת אתערותא דלתתא, **אבל בשלמות הגאולה שאז יהיו שני העצים לאחד בידי, ביד ה׳, אז יהיו גם הם כתרין ריעין דלא מתפרשין והיו שניהם לאחד, למלך המשיח** שהוא בדרגת רעיא מהימנא של הגואל האחרון שהוא משה רבנו ע״ה, **בדרגת האלף הגדול והיה ה׳ למלך על כל הארץ וכו׳, (וכן בחושבנא ״משיח בן יוסף משיח בן דויד״ עולה למספר אלף).** ובעמדנו על סף האתחלתא עלינו ללמוד ולדעת את כל הבחינות והתפקידים של ב׳ המשיחין, משיחין תתאין, בדרכי האתחלתא בסע״ד.

It also follows the haftorah ([Yechezkel 37:19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14256&st=&pgnum=323) which is based upon parshat VaYigash, Bereshit 44:18) discussing the joining together of the *branch of Yosef* and the *branch of Yehudah* to become one.

According to the Lubavitcher Rebbe of our generation, Rabbi Menachem Mendel Scheersohn, this appears to be why Rambam in Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Melachim, chapters 11 and 12 does not mention Moshiach ben Yosef at all. The Rebbe explains in Torato shel Moshiach, Chapter 11, pg 67 that even though Moshiach ben Yosef is mentioned throughout the Talmud, midrash and Prophets, Rambam is completely silent about him when discussing Moshiach in halacha. The Rebbe says this suggests that Rambam is of the view that Moshiach ben Yosef and Moshiach ben David are the same individual at different stages of the redemption.

> אף דמדמפטיריו בשבת חוהמ׳ס ביום בוא גוג (מגילה לא:א) מפני  דבתשרי תהי׳ מלחמת גוג (טוש׳ע א׳ח ס׳ תט) משמע לכאורה דס׳ל דבתשרי נגאלין י״ל **דהיינו דוקא מלחמת גוג שהיא תחלת ימוה״מ** כדמוכח׳ קרא׳ וכדאיתא ברמב״ם הלכות מלכים (פרק יב:ב). אבל הגאולה תהי׳ בניסן **וצ״ע אם הגאולה  היא לפני מלחמת גוג או לאחרי׳** ועיין סנהדרין (צז:ב) מהן מלחמת גו״מ והשאר ימוה״מ ופירש״י **שכלה השעבוד ומשיח בא.** אבל בעבודה זרה (ג:ב) משמע להיפך דאיתא שם: **אין מקבלין גרים לימוה״מ כו״ אלא שנעשו גרים גרורים כיון  שראוין  מלחמת גו״מ כו״.** ועיין ג״כ ויקרא רבה (פ׳ל פ׳ה) **דימוה״מ קודמים למלחמת גו״מ.** ולכאורה י״ל **דהגאולה מהחלה שקודם למלחמת גו״מ אבל אין הגאולה שלימה אלא אחרי מפלה גו״מ** - ועיין ג״כ רש״י ד״ה אתחלתא (מגילה יז:ב)  ומ״ש רש״י (סנהדרין צז:ב) ומשיח בא - **היינו משיח בן דוד הבא לאחר התחלת גו״מ כדמשמע בסוכה (נב:א)**. **משא״כ משיח בן יוסף** הנלחם עם גו״מ, **שבו מתחיל כללות ימוה״מ והוא קודם לגו״מ**. ועיין ג״כ יחזקאל (לח-לט) וזכרי׳ (יב-יד). **וצ״ע שברמב״ם סוף הלכות מלכים השמיט לגמרי ענין משיח בן יוסף, ומשמע מלשונו שם דהכל נעשה ע״י משיח בן דוד.**

One of the points to note about this is that the individual who actually transitions from the time of exile to the days of Moshiach is the single person mentioned by Rambam in Hilchot Melachim chapters 11 and 12 who will embody both roles of Moshiach ben Yosef and Moshiach ben David. The branch of Yehudah and the branch of Yosef will become one in *My hand*.

All those *potential Moshiachs* from previous generations who did not make the transition from the days of exile to the days of Moshiach remain in the valid and legitimate status of *Moshiach ben Yosef*. Or in the words of Rambam, they are "like all the perfect and fit kings from the house of David who have died."

And this leads to the posuk referring to *Ben David.*

> התנערי מעפר קומי, לבשי בגדי תפארתך עמי, על יד בן ישי בית הלחמי, קרבה אל נפשי גאלה

Ben Yishai, meaning David ben Yishai (**דוד** בן ישי, That **יד** is gematria **דוד**.), refers to Moshiach ben David (משיח בן **דוד**), like is found in the commentary of the *Maharid*, Rabbi Yitzchok DovBer of Liadi in volume 2 of Siddur HaTefillah al-pi Nusach HaAri z"l explaining Lecha Dodi. In this stage of the redemption Moshiach ben David is destined to be resurrected as one of the seven shepherds and eight anointed individuals who are the first to be resurrected: David HaMelech, Adam, Seth ben Adam, Metushelach, Avraham Avinu, Yaacov Avinu, Moshe Rabbeinu, Yishai, Shaul HaMelech, Shmuel HaNavi, Amos HaNavi, Tzephaniah HaNavi, Tzidikyahu HaMelech, and Eliyahu HaNavi like is found in Sukkot 52b. That is the reference to *'awaken and arise from the dust'* (התנערי מעפר קומי), like from the expression *Arise and sing you sleepers in the dust* (קיצו ורננו שוכני עפר) from Isaiah 26:19.

It also follows the explanation of Rabbeinu Bechaye to Bereshit 1:3.

> **ויאמר אלהים יהי אור.** ירמוז על ימות המשיח שהזכיר בו הכתוב (ישעיה ס:א) קומי אורי כי בא אורך וכבוד ה' עליך זרח.

***And G-d said, Let there be light*** alludes to the *Days of Moshiach* which are recalled in the text of Isaiah 60:1, "Arise my light because Your light has come, and the *glory of the L-rd is upon you* is Zerach."

In other words, because *Your light* has come, my light rises. The posuk goes on to associate this aspect of *my light* with *Zerach* (זרח). It is discussing the concept that the aspect of *Zerach* only arises as a consequence of *Your light*, meaning the light of Moshiach ben Yosef having already come.

And this leads to the next line of the poem which actually cites the posuk from Isaiah brought by Rabbeinu Bechaye.

> התעוררי התעוררי, כי בא אורך קומי אורי, עורי עורי שיר דברי, כבוד הוי׳ עליך נגלה

You have surely caused me to be aroused, because your light has come my light arises, I am surely aroused, a song leads me, 'the glory of the L-rd is upon you' is revealed.

This *light of Moshiach ben Yosef* is referring to the culmination of his life's purpose which is called *the elevation of the sparks of holiness*. These sparks fell at the beginning of creation through the shattering of the vessels as described by the Ari z"l and many others. As the Ari teaches, this is the ingathering of the exiles (קבוץ גליות) mentioned in the Amidah prayer. Unlike the final, literal ingathering of the exiles mentioned in Tehillim and in halacha, the ingathering mentioned in the Amidah prayer precedes the re-establishment of the Sanhedrin and the rebuilding of the Temple. This follows the teachings of the Alter Rebbe who follows the teachings of the Ari as found in the [Igrot Kodesh of Rabbi Shalom Dov Ber Shneersohn, volume 1, letter 130](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31622&st=&pgnum=360).

> אמנם בדבר אשר אחד יצא מקהל עדתם והראה **ענין קיבוץ גליות המבואר בסידור רבינו נ״ע** ע״פ תהלתו בקהל חסידים, הלא כל רואה יראה **שזהו בגמר הבירורים וכמ״ש שם וז״ל אך הנה ענין קיבוץ גליות היינו לאחר שיושלם בחי׳ הבירור כו׳ וכן כתב אח״כ אחר שכבר עשו ותקנו מה שביכולתם לתקן כו׳.** ובכתבים נמצא ג״כ ע״פ הנ׳׳ל ושם נא׳ מפורש וז״ל **אך לע״ל בגמר ותכלית כל הברורין שיתקבצו כל האורות דתהו שנתפזרו בבחי׳ קיבוץ והתכללות באחד אז גם החסדים שנתפזרו בשבילם יתקבצו ויתאספו בבחי׳ קיבוץ להתעלות למקורן אחד חפשוט, עכ״ל. וענין קיבוץ גליות ברוחניות הוא אסיפת וקיבוץ נצוצי החסדים וגם אסיפת וקיבוץ נצוצי הגבורות הן הניצוצות דתוהו הנבררים ע״י ניצוצי החסדים ונכללים בהם וכמש׳׳ש בסידור** בענין והטבך וחרבך מאבותיך כו׳. **ועמש״ש ע״פ נדחי ישראל יכנס דשרש ענין קיבוץ גליות הוא בירור ועליות נצוצות דתוהו, והיינו דנש״י לפי שהן בבחי׳ החסדים דשם מ״ה וירדו תתלבשו בלבושי נוגה ולזאת בעבודתם ופעולתם המה מבררים את הנצוצות דתהו שנפלו בק״נ, ולעתיד בגמר הברורים יתאספו ויתקבצו נצוצי חחסדים והגבורות ויתעלו בבחי׳ אחד פשוט. ובפע״ח בכוונת ברכת קיבוץ גליות דהיינו ברכת תקע בשופר כ׳ שהו״ע בירור ועליות הנצוצות כו׳ ושם לכוין בשם היוצא מפסוק חיל בלע ויקאנו דהיינו הוצאות-הנצוצות מהם שיתעלו אל
>   הקדושה וזחו״ע קיבוץ גליות )ומ״ש שם בפע׳׳ח עוד בענין חנ״ל** עמ׳׳ש בסידור ע״פ עושה משפט לעשוקים(.

This elevation of the sparks of holiness is accomplished via the passing away of Moshiach ben Yosef and his soul ascending to its source. This is called *histalkut* (הסתלקות). The sparks cleave to his soul and ascend with him. In so doing, Moshiach ben Yosef completes the tikkun that all the Jewish people through all the generations have accomplished through the performance of the mitzvot. This is also alluded to by Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato in his sefer, [Derech HaShem, section 2:3:8](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A_%D7%94%27_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%92), which discusses the single individual who is so refined that he causes not only the tikkun of himself and his generation but also all the generations which preceded him.

> ואמנם כיון **שהם בעצמם שלימים וראוים לטוב** שהם מתיסרין רק בעבור האחרים ודאי שתתפיס מדת הדין במועט בהם כבמרובה בחוטאים עצמם. ולא עוד אלא שעל ידי זה זכותם נוסף וכחם מתחזק וכל שכן שיכולים לתקן את אשר עיותו האחרים. **והיינו כי לא די שיתקנו למה שבבני דורם אלא גם לענין כל מה שנתקלקל העולם מאז נהיו בו חטאים ועד עתה.** ובודאי **שאלה יהיו אחר כך בקיבוץ השלימים ראשי הראשים והיותר קרובים אליו ית**':

The next two posukim in the poem are discussing the period from the histalkut of Moshiach ben Yosef until the appearance of Moshiach ben David, meaning until his resurrection.

לא תבושי ולא תכלמי, מה תשתוחחי ומה תהמי, בך יחסו עניי עמי, ונבנתה העיר על תלה: והיו למשיסה שאסיך, ורחקו כל מבלעיך, ישיש עליך אלהיך, כמשוש חתן על כלה:

It discusses how those who remain after Moshiach ben Yosef have passed away will be tested greatly in their faith and even harassed by those around them. It is a plea that they not be included among those who are embarrassed about the redemption because of the judgement that has befallen Moshiach ben Yosef. This is based upon the Torah teachings found in [Sefer Avkat Rochel by Rabbeinu Makir ben Abba Mori, book one, part one, sign seven](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21524&st=&pgnum=10), about the coming of Moshiach and elsewhere.

> **וכל מי שלבו מסופק בדינו** חוזר על אומות
>   העולם ואומרים זו הגאולה שאנו מחכים לה שהמשיח נהרג. **וכל מי שאינו 
>   מצפה לגאולה מתבייש ממנה** וחוזר על אומות העולם

The ninth line of the poem is:

> ימין ושמאל תפרוצי, ואת הוי׳ תעריצי, על יד איש בן פרצי, ונשמחה ונגילה

The (aspect of) right and left will be broken through, and I, Ish ben Partzi, will praise the L-rd, and be happy and rejoice.

This *elevation of the sparks* has two aspects to it, one associated with Chesed (חסד, kindness) which is associated with the right and one which is associated with gevurah (גבורה, severity) which is associated with the left.

Ben Partzi is referring to Moshiach ben Yosef who breaks through  from the time of exile to the time called 'the days of Moshiach' which is the end of exile and the beginning of the final redemption as mentioned in [Yalkut Shimoni on Isaiah 499](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9758&st=&pgnum=122). Peretz is the root of Ufaratzta, ופרצת, and is an expression of breaking through and crossing over. This concept of Peretz and Zerach follows the explanation of [Ramban to Bereshit 38:29](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=504) discussing the concepts of the twin brothers, Peretz and Zerach.

> וענין פרץ בכל מקום נתיצת הגדר ועברו.

"The concept of Peretz in all places is *breaking through* and *crossing over*."

Zerach, whose hand hand emerged before Peretz but withdrew, is compared to the sun. Because his hand emerged first, Zerach is the bachor and is equated with Moshiach ben David. Peretz who was born first, meaning he was the first to emerge from the womb completely, is compared to the moon and establishes the paradigm of Moshiach ben Yosef. This is because the light of the moon is secondary to the light of the sun. The moons light appears and then disappears while the light of the sun is constant.

It would seem reasonable according to this that since Zerach is the firstborn, meaning the bachor who takes precedence over Peretz, that Moshiach ben David should come first. But Peretz, meaning Moshiach ben Yosef, preceding Moshiach ben David actually is a consequence of the blessing of Yaacov Avinu to the children of Yosef HaTzaddik, namely Ephraim and Menashe like is found in [Bereshit, parshat Vayechi, 48:8-22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=624). This is discussed in Midrash Tanchuma, parshat Naso, siman 29.

> לא יאמר אדם איני מקיים מצות זקנים הואיל ואינן מן התורה, אמר להם הקב"ה בני אין אתם רשאין לומר כך אלא כל מה שגוזרים עליכם תהיו מקיימין שנא' (דברים י) ועשית על פי התורה אשר יורוך, למה שאף על דבריהם אני מסכים שנאמר (איוב כב) ותגזר אומר ויקם לך, תדע לך שהרי יעקב בשעה שברך מנשה ואפרים מה כתיב שם (בראשית מח) **וישם את אפרים לפני מנשה, עשה הקטן קודם לגדול, וקיים הקב"ה גזרתו**, אימתי בקרבנות הנשיאים שהקריב שבט אפרים תחלה שנא' ביום השביעי נשיא לבני אפרים ואח"כ מנשה מנין ממה שקראו בעניין ביום השמיני נשיא לבני מנשה

That the blessing of Yaacov Avinu changed the natural order so that the younger, meaning in context Peretz, Moshiach ben Yosef who is associated with Ephraim, would precede the Bachor, Zerach, meaning Moshiach ben David who is associated with Menashe. And this also is emphasized in the Yalkut Shimoni cited above where Moshiach is referred to as *Ephraim, My righteous Moshiach* (אפרים משיח צדקי).

It is worth noting that the Midrash Tanchuma goes on to ask, "When does this change in precedence apply?" It says this applies when they make the dedication of the Mishkan and bring their offerings. Ephraim precedes Menashe and brings his offering on Shabbat. Menashe brings his offering on the eighth day. Not only is this a change in the precedence of Bachor to second born. A korban brought by an individual (קרבן יחיד אינו דוחה את השבת) is normally not permitted on Shabbat. This emphasizes the special connection of Peretz, meaning Ephraim, My righteous Moshiach, Moshiach ben Yosef to ending the time of exile and bringing in Shabbat. And all of this is in connection with establishing the Temple and bringing the korbanot because as the Sages say, "The Mishkan is the Mikdash and the Mikdash is the Mishkan."

This is the same blessing that all Jews traditionally make on their children erev Shabbat, that they should be like Ephraim and Menashe. It is to emphasize our prayer for Chiddush HaOlam which comes through Ephraim like is explained by [Rav Dovid Dov Lebanon](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/3022).

It could also be thought that this blessing from Yaacov is only about children, but the explicit text in the posuk which follows this blessing explains what Yaacov Avinu was referring to [(Bereshit, 49:1)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=632).

> וַיִּקְרָ֥א יַעֲקֹ֖ב אֶל־בָּנָ֑יו וַיֹּ֗אמֶר הֵאָֽסְפוּ֙ וְאַגִּ֣ידָה לָכֶ֔ם אֵ֛ת אֲשֶׁר־יִקְרָ֥א אֶתְכֶ֖ם בְּאַחֲרִ֥ית הַיָּמִֽים׃

This is also the view of the Ari z"l as cited above in the letter ofRabbi Shalom Dov Ber Schneersohn quoting Sefer Pri Etz Chaim and Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato in his Ma'amar HaGeulah.

Two excellent sources for commentaries to Lecha Dodi are [Siddur HaTefillah al-pi Nusach HaAri z"l with the commentary of the Maharid](http://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HP-SM) and the [Siddur Kol Yaacov](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6755&st=&pgnum=252).

Comment: I've never seen a translation that accords with this translation of "פרצי". [Chabad's translation](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/265789/jewish/Lcha-Dodi.htm), [another Chabad translation](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380392/jewish/Lecha-Dodi-new-translation.htm), [Wikipedia's translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lekhah_Dodi), Artscroll's translation, etc. all indicate it refers to Peretz the ancestor of Boaz. Can you [edit] in a source for this claim?